# Eliminate unused dependency in a switch-case

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code that looks like

```
#include "foo.h"  // defines int foo()
#include "bar.h"  // defines int bar()
#include "baz.h"  // defines int baz()

enum MyEnum {
  FOO,
  BAR,
  BAZ
};

int myFunction(const std::vector<MyEnum>& my_enums) {
  int ret = 0;
  for (auto my_enum : my_enums) {
    switch (my_enum) {
      case FOO:
        ret += foo();
        break;
      case BAR:
        ret += bar();
        break;
      case BAZ:
        ret += baz();
        break;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

The problem with this code is that, when I call `myFunction({FOO, BAR})`, it would still link `baz.h` into the binary. If I know `my_enums` at compile time, is there a way to eliminate this unused dependency?

Comment: One common way is to use macros for this. Here is an example: https://github.com/Thalhammer/jwt-cpp/blob/master/include/jwt-cpp/jwt.h Switch-cases are evaluated at runtime, not at compile time.

Comment: `std::vector` is the wrong type for representing values that must be known at compile time.  Templates are known at compile time.  Try `myFunction<FOO, BAR>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a switch-case statement. It's evaluated at runtime, not at compile time.

One common way is to use macros for this

```
#ifdef ENABLE_FOO
#include "foo.h"  // defines int foo()
#endif
#ifdef ENABLE_BAR
#include "bar.h"  // defines int bar()
#endif
#ifdef ENABLE_BAZ
#include "baz.h"  // defines int baz()
#endif

enum MyEnum {
  FOO,
  BAR,
  BAZ
};

int myFunction(const std::vector<MyEnum>& my_enums) {
  int ret = 0;
  for (auto my_enum : my_enums) {
    switch (my_enum) {
      #ifdef ENABLE_FOO
      case FOO:
        ret += foo();
        break;
      #endif
      #ifdef ENABLE_BAR
      case BAR:
        ret += bar();
        break;
      #endif
      #ifdef ENABLE_BAZ
      case BAZ:
        ret += baz();
        break;
      #endif
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

You can select the dependencies at compile time, e.g. with

```
g++ -DENABLE_FOO -DENABLE_BAR main.cpp -o main
```